# Running out of memory in Keras with smaller CNN

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, artificial-intelligence, tflearn

Hello everyone I'm having a weird problem.

I got data that is the image and the output which is the joystick info and keyboard.
The model that I don't have problems running out of memory(and crashing) is inception_v3 which is so much complex than a simple CNN(for that reason I think it's weird).

https://github.com/Sentdex/pygta5/blob/efdd66841ff909a027a42ebb48facbd63670e281/models.py#L219

I'm trying to apply a keras model based on one for MNIST and changing the input size.

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/9c689775a22f9e8647207eeae012978048d44bed/examples/mnist_cnn.py#L47

The output before crashing is this more than one time. It starts to do the epoch so I think it's not a problem with the shape of the data.

```
> 2018-05-07 23:03:22.080446: W T:\src\github\tensorflow\tensorflow\core\framework\allocator.cc:101] Allocation of 1037238272 exceeds 10% of system memory.
```

Comment: Try to use a smaller `batch_size`, e.g. 32.

Comment: No, that doesn't work